# SQL need to repress one type of row

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

I have some data being used in a crystal report.
the data looks like this. There is some redundancy in the data. the only difference is the `Tran_code`

```
Sales_Rep   Tran_code   Order#   Amt
------------------------------------
Joe         001         1234  100.00
Joe         WOC         1234  100.00

Jon         001         5555   50.00

Sue         001         7777   70.00
Sue         WOC         7777   70.00
Sue         QUE         7777   70.00
```

If an order has only the `001` `Tran_code`, we want to show that `001`, along with the other columns.

But if it has other codes, then we don't want to show the `001`
even in the case of Sue, we would want to show `WOC` and `QUE`.

I am looking for SQL that will present the data as needed to the CR. as far as redundant I can do that in the Crystal grouping.

Comment: What database are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: data is coming from ibm i. I made a table so far that tells me the count of tran_codes. so i can know which is a 001 only. am tring to use this in the cr.

Comment: What @Goat is asking for is your current SQL code. If you have something, post it and we can revise it for you. Otherwise you are asking us to write it from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your desired result was:

```
Sales_Rep   Tran_code   Order#   Amt
------------------------------------
<row omitted>
Joe         WOC         1234  100.00

Jon         001         5555   50.00

<row omitted>
Sue         WOC         7777   70.00
Sue         QUE         7777   70.00
```

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE
( Tran_code = '001' 
  AND 0 = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM table1 AS t2
    WHERE t1.Sales_Rep = t2.Sales_Rep
    AND   t1.Order  = t2.Order
    AND Tran_code <> '001'))
OR
Tran_code <> '001'
```

There may be more efficient ways to write this, but I'm going for obvious here.